# MVC3: The name 'functionname' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have both web form and MVC3 at my web application. I have a function which works fine under web form. I tried to reference it in MVC controller.Because I need this function's return value in my MVC controller.So I put function's inherits namespace under MVC controller. But it says 'The name 'functionname' does not exist in the current context.'

For example: I have a function name 'getClaimValue' under PortalUserControl:

```
namespace Site.Control {public class PortalUserControl:PortalViewUserControl{ public string getClaimValue(){...}}}
```

so I put `using Site.Control` under my MVC controller

```
using Site.Control ; namespace Site.Areas.Account.Controllers{public class AccountController:Controller{[HttpGet]public ActionResult SignIn(){string claimValue=getCliamValue();} }}
```

So I get red line under 'getClaimValue()' says 'The name does not exist in the current context.'
So how can I make it work?
Thank.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing master pages with base classes. A page does not inherit from a master page. A master page provides templated presentation and layout, but does not usually have public methods. You may want to create a base class for your controller and put your method there.

Comment: Sorry, I use a bad example. see my question again, I changed it a litte bit.